# For loop a pointer char in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have a code that is supposed to get the time , I want to store the time in my char array but I cannot do that so , I thought that I could have a loop to a pointer and loop through the pointer and copy the chars from the pointer memory to my char, is that possible?

```
void My_Time(char *myt_Time,int size) 
{
    time_t raw_Time = time(0);
    struct tm *info;
    char *myt_Temp;
    int x;

        info = localtime(&raw_Time);
        myt_Temp = asctime(info);
        for (x=0;x<size;x++)
        {
          myt_Time[x]=myt_Temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to stop when you reach the trailing NULL in `myt_Temp`. You can use `strncpy` to do this, instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: Also, it should be `myt_Time[x] = myt_Temp[x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your problem, the following code should work, instead of your `for` loop.

`strncpy(myt_Time, mytTemp, size);`

The bug in your `for` loop is there:

`myt_Time[x]=myt_Temp;` => `myt_Time[x]=myt_Temp[x];`

Comment: `SIZE_OF_MYT_TIME` should just be `size`.